# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'itid=1' at line 1

Tags: java, mysql

You have an error in your `SQL` syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your `MySQL` server version for the right syntax to use near `itid=1` at line 1

when i am trying to generate bill for my billing application the above error will appeared.
following is the code for my application.
please give me some solutions to solve this error....thanks in advance

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{   
    String str1=(String)ae.getActionCommand();
    Object source = ae.getSource();
    if(source==home)
    {
        this.dispose();
        home t=new home();
        t.nn("","","","");
    }
    if(source==add)
    {
        name.setEditable(false);
        pho.setEditable(false);
        da.setEditable(false);

        try
        {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/billing", "root", "");
        Statement stm = c.createStatement();
        t=0;
        if(pho.getText().length()!=10&&pho.getText().length()!=0)
        jp.showMessageDialog(this,"Phone Number Must Have 10 Digits","INFORMATION",jp.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        else
        {   
                        ResultSet rs1 = stm.executeQuery("select * from bill where billid="+bid.getText()+"and itid="+id.getText());
            while(rs1.next())
            {   
                t=1;
            }
            if(t==0)
            {
                t=0;
            PreparedStatement ps  = c.prepareStatement("insert into bill values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            if((bid.getText()).length()!=0)
            ps.setString(1,bid.getText());
            else
            ps.setString(1,"");
            if((name.getText()).length()!=0)
            ps.setString(2,name.getText()); 
            else
            ps.setString(2,""); 
            if((pho.getText()).length()!=0)
            ps.setString(3,pho.getText());
            else
            ps.setString(3,"");
            if((da.getText()).length()!=0)
            ps.setString(4,da.getText());
            else
            ps.setString(4,"");
            if((id.getText()).length()!=0)
            ps.setString(5,id.getText());
            else
            ps.setString(5,"");
            if((co.getText()).length()!=0)
            ps.setString(6,co.getText());
            else
            ps.setString(6,"");

            ps.executeUpdate();
            //jp.showMessageDialog(this,"Record Inserted Successfully","SUCCESS",jp.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            it[cu]=Integer.parseInt(id.getText());
            coun[cu++]=Integer.parseInt(co.getText());

            }
            else
            {
                jp.showMessageDialog(this,"Sorry, Item ID is Already Entered","INFORMATION",jp.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                t=0;
            }

        }

        c.close();
        stm.close();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnf)
        {
            System.out.println("Cnf Exception");
        }
        catch(SQLException sql)
        {
            jp.showMessageDialog(this,sql,"EXCEPTION",jp.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    if(source==reset)
    {
        id.setEditable(true);
        id.setText(null);
    }
    if(source==ge)
    {
        //this.dispose();
        res u1=new res();
        u1.n1(it,coun,cu);
    }
}
```

### Table structure for table `bill`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bill` (
  `billid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `cus` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `pho` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
 `day` date NOT NULL,
 `itid` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `count` int(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never forgett the spaces:

```
"select * from bill where billid="+bid.getText()+" and itid="+id.getText()
```

and please use `PreparedStatement`:

```
PreparedStatement lPreparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("select * from bill where billid=? and itid=?");
lPreparedStatement.setInt(1, Integer.valueOf(bid.getText()));
lPreparedStatement.setInt(2, Integer.valueOf(id.getText()));
```

**Furthermore:**

1. a phonenumber should also be a VARCHAR. What do you do if your
   customer has the phone number +49176/128383? You have to save the
   "+" and "/" also and thats not possible with a numeric datatype.
2. for Date use setDate not setString (see column day)
3. for int and Integer use setInt not setString

Comment: thanks Stefan for your answer but after trying this solved above error but getting another error i.e. Unkown column '2itid' in 'where clause'

Comment: looks for me you dont paste the original sql. 2itid is a concatination of the value from billid and the column name itid. are you sure that you have inserted the "and" keyword between billid and itid?

Comment: Do what Stefan suggests. It is the correct answer. If you still have a problem it is probably unrelated and perhaps worth asking another question.

Comment: thanks...it works but occurred another error i.e Incorrect integer value:" for column 'pho' at row 1

Comment: yes you have to insert the correct data type for each column. in your case you insert String everytime.

Comment: there is no and keyword between billid and itid

Comment: for example: count is an int in your table but you try to insert String. that must fail.

Comment: You should use`ps.setInt()` instead of `ps.setString()` because pho is an integer column.

Comment: if((pho.getText()).length()!=0)
    ps.setInt(3, Integer.valueOf(pho.getText()));
    else
    ps.setString(3,"");   i have changed pho column but getting same error i.e. incorrect integer value